# Limit the size of the disk driver cache on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, drivers, filesystems, cache

I am running some experiments for comparing storage systems under load in Linux. To this end I want to force the file system to access the disk itself without caching too much data on RAM.

How can I explicitly specify to the device driver that I want to limit its in-memory cache size?

Currently the device is mounted using ext4, but this is not a limitation, I can use whatever works.

Comment: If you want to force the filesystem to access the disk itself, you should just open the file in the bypass-cache mode, rather than trying to shrink the system cache.